# HIVE ESCAPED BY

Tags: arrays, hive, escaping, adobe-brackets

I have exported data from a hive table.then I created another table  to read those files.
My hive source table has an array field which looks like ['9x3','970x66','728x90','970x90','970x250','980x300','1200x300','970x418'].
My target external hive table also need to look the same.
When I export data, the array field has '[]' as expected.
However since my target field also is an array, it adds additional '[]'.
I have used escaped by, but could not find a way to escape both '[' and ']' characters.
I have used:

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '['
    COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\,'
    MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
```

and tried multiple versions such as

```
ESCAPED BY '[]', 
ESCAPED BY '[|]',
ESCAPED BY '[,]'
```

all seems to escape only the first character.
Is there any way to escape multiple characters, or any way to export the array fields without '[]' characters.regexp_replace and translate functions don't work for me.
Thanks

source array
['970x66','728x90','970x90','970x250','980x300','1200x300','970x418']

need target array:    ['970x66','728x90','970x90','970x250','980x300','1200x300','970x418']

but it looks without escape        ['['970x66','728x90','970x90','970x250','980x300','1200x300','970x418']']

Answer (score 0):

You could use `concat_ws(string delimiter, array<string>)` to convert the array to a string and export it instead of using the `ESCAPED BY`

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\,'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':'
SELECT 
      rest_of_columns,
      concat_ws(',',collect_set(cast(arrayfieldname) as string)) as array_field 
FROM 
      yourtable;
```